# Can you scan excel sheets for columns that have creditcard format data via C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm working on a card number masking process. We get these human created excel documents in and need to mask a set of the digits, but its not always guaranteed that Column D is going to be the column with the card numbers. Could be Column D only, or D and G, etc. I know these documents will always have at least 10 rows not counting headers.

I want to run a scan of the worksheets in an excel workbook and detect which columns have data, then check the 3rd cell of each non null column. If it matches a numerical string at least 9 digits long, define that column as a card type in an array, then go back and iterate through the array of columns meeting that requirement and mask the desired characters. Is this reasonably doable between some C# methods and excel properties within the Interops library?

Comment: Yes it is. Although using something like LinqToExcel would probably be easier - https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do so. There are several libraries out there, that give you access to Excel documents and let you scan through worksheets, rows, columns and cell values.

Some libraries are based on the Interop COM interface Excel and start a background Excel process that does the real work of extracting the information.

Libraries like NPOI (for xls and xlsx) or the Open XML SDK (xlsx) access Excel files directly without the need of having Excel installed. This is extremly valuable for server side processing of Office documents. In NPOI sweeping through a Excel file looks like this (just to give you an idea).

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
var rowEnumerator = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();
while (rowEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
        IRow row = (XSSFRow)_rowEnumerator.Current;

        int colCount = row.LastCellNum;
        var tableRow = new TableRow(colCount);
        for (var c = 0; c < colCount; c++)
        {
            var cell = row.GetCell(c);
            if (cell != null)
            {
                 if (IsCreditCardNumber(c))
                 {
                     ...
                 }
            }
        }
}
```